# HTML Link disabled from opening into window

Tags: php, html, css, sql, phpmyadmin

```
echo "<tr><th align='left'><a href=\"$email\">$name</a></th>
```

I converted a PHP Email App into a saving app. And I am having a problem being able to open a link within the application.

Here is a live example of the app online - [Link](http://www.andulicsdesign.com/Blakes/)

The PHP code has converted the links on the page into mailto links. I cant figure out how to just get the links to be displayed normal.

Is there a way I can convert the link to be displayed normally without being opened as email links? 
Any help is appreciated

Im sure its something simple, but I don't understand it.

Thank you,

```
echo "<tr><th align='left'><a href=\"$email\">$name</a></th>
                  <th class='right'>$submitDate</th></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>".nl2br(htmlspecialchars($content))."<br/></td></tr>";
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

If the e-mails are in the format of `mailto:somemail@mail.com` you could try:

```
$cleanEmail = str_replace("mailto:","", $oldEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code that I am working with -

I am mostly trying to work with this piece of code. Everytime I try to delete the backslashes and $email the app throws an error. Is there a way I can display the links correctly? Right now there being displayed, but when I cant even open them. :( -

```
echo "<tr><th align='left'><a href=\"$email\">$name</a></th>

<?php
class maxGuestbook{
   var $messageDir = 'messages';
   var $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d g:i:s A';
   var $itemsPerPage = 200;
   var $messageList;

function processGuestbook(){
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $this->insertMessage();
   }
   $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

   $this->displayGuestbook($page);
}

function getMessageList(){

   $this->messageList = array();

    // Open the actual directory
    if ($handle = @opendir($this->messageDir)) {
        // Read all file from the actual directory
        while ($file = readdir($handle))  {
            if (!is_dir($file)) {
               $this->messageList[] = $file;
        }
        }
    }   

    rsort($this->messageList);

    return $this->messageList;
}   

function displayGuestbook($page=1){
      $list = $this->getMessageList();
      //echo "<center><a href='add.php'>Leave a message</a></center>";
      echo "<table class='newsList'>";

      //Get start point and end point
      $startItem = ($page-1)*$this->itemsPerPage;
      if (($startItem + $this->itemsPerPage) > sizeof($list)) $endItem = sizeof($list);
      else $endItem = $startItem + $this->itemsPerPage; 

      for ($i=$startItem;$i<$endItem;$i++){
         //foreach ($list as $value) {
         $value = $list[$i];
        $data = file($this->messageDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
        $name  = trim($data[0]);
        $email = trim($data[1]);
         $submitDate = trim($data[2]);  
         unset ($data['0']);
         unset ($data['1']);
         unset ($data['2']);

         $content = "";
         foreach ($data as $value) {
               $content .= $value;
         }

        echo "<tr><th align='left'><a href=\"$email\">$name</a></th>
                  <th class='right'>$submitDate</th></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>".nl2br(htmlspecialchars($content))."<br/></td></tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
      if (sizeof($list) == 0){
         echo "<center><p>No messages at the moment!</p><p>&nbsp;</p></center>";
      }
      // Create pagination
      if (sizeof($list) > $this->itemsPerPage){
         echo "<div id=\"navigation\">";
         if ($startItem == 0) {
            if ($endItem < sizeof($list)){
               echo "<div id=\"nright\"><a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?page=".($page+1)."\" >Next &raquo;</a></div>";
            } else {
               // Nothing to display
            }
         } else {
            if ($endItem < sizeof($list)){
               echo "<div id=\"nleft\"><a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?page=".($page-1)."\" >&laquo; Prev</a></div>";
               echo "<div id=\"nright\"><a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?page=".($page+1)."\" >Next &raquo;</a></div>";
            } else {
               echo "<div id=\"nleft\"><a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?page=".($page-1)."\" >&laquo; Prev</a></div>";
            }
         }

         echo "<br/></div><br/>";
      }
      echo "<hr />";
      $this->displayAddForm();
}

function displayAddForm(){
?>  
  <form class="iform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    Website Link<br/>
    <input type="text" name="name" size="30"/><br/><br/>
    Contact Name<br/>
    <input type="text" name="email" size="30"/><br/><br/>
    Job Link Information<br/>
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="49"></textarea><br/>
    <center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" /></center>
  </form> 

<?php   
}

function insertMessage(){
   $name   = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : 'Anonymous';
   $email  = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
   $submitDate  = date($this->dateFormat);
   $content = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : '';

   if (trim($name) == '') $name = 'Anonymous';
   if (strlen($content)<5) {
      exit();
   }

   $filename = date('YmdHis');
   if (!file_exists($this->messageDir)){
      mkdir($this->messageDir);
   }
   $f = fopen($this->messageDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename.".txt","w+");         
   fwrite($f,$name."\n");
   fwrite($f,$email."\n");
   fwrite($f,$submitDate."\n");
   fwrite($f,$content."\n");
   fclose($f);

}
}
?>
```